# Alguien sabe porque me sale de esta manera al querer concatenar con coma(,) en pycharm?

Tags: python

```
miDia = int(input("¿Como estuvo tu dia del 1 al 10?"))
print("Mi dia estuvo de:", miDia)
```

resultado: ('Mi dia estuvo de:', 9)

Comment: Acabo de probar ésto en python 3.10 y la salida es `Mi dia estuvo de: 3`. Qué versión de python usas? (`python -V`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir distintos tipos de variables hay que castearlas primero.

```
print("Mi día estuvo de: "+ str(miDia) )
```

Ejemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp

Comment: ahi me salio, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

el print sería así:
Print("Mi día estuvo de: "+","+miDia

En el caso que quieras la coma, si no la quieres:
Print("Mi día estuvo de: " + miDia)

Comment: print("Mi día estuvo de: "+","+miDia)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Mejor usar f-string que concatenar `print(f"Mi día estuvo de: {miDia}")`

Comment: @CandidMoe los f-string son algo agregado en Python 3.6 (un poco reciente), por lo que por ahora sigue siendo valido no usarlos. Sin embargo, concuerdo con que es mejor usar .format o el operador % antes de concatenar.